# How can you completely 'close and clear' FBSession's activeSession information from within your iOS application?

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

I'm currently creating an iOS application that allows users to connect/disconnect their facebook accounts from within my application's settings view controller. Facebook's SDK Developer Documentation advises calling the 'closeAndClearTokenInformation' method on the FBSession.activeSession Class which 'Closes the in-memory session, and clears any persisted cache related to the session' according to the documentation.

I've researched this problem, and noticed multiple people experiencing the same discrepancy with Facebook's SDK; specifically, that after 'closing and clearing' the activeSession, upon opening up a new session, the application jumps to iphone's browser(fast-switches), but doesn't prompt the user to login with their facebook credentials. Instead, the user is notified that "They are already authorized with this application, and that they should press 'Okay' to continue."

I was expecting Facebook's SDK to prompt the user to type in their email/phone number & password once again since I cleared their session information from the previous session. I've also removed all token information from the User Defaults in tandem with 'clearing and closing' the session in hopes that this would resolve my issue, but this problem still persists.

Here is how I'm trying to clear my Facebook Session Information:

```
[[FBSession activeSession] closeAndClearTokenInformation];
[[FBSession activeSession] close];
[FBSession setActiveSession:nil];
NSLog(@"The active facebook session: %@", [[FBSession activeSession] description]);
```

This is what my Output Console displays:

```
2013-04-01 17:07:11.759 RoyalCourt Debug[4728:c07] The active facebook session:
<FBSession: 0xb86e060, state: FBSessionStateCreated, loginHandler: 0x0, appID:
164860420329245, urlSchemeSuffix: , tokenCachingStrategy:<FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy:
0xb864650>, expirationDate: (null), refreshDate: (null), 
attemptedRefreshDate: 0001-12-30 00:00:00 +0000, permissions:()>
```

I would like to know:

1. Where is the previous session information being stored and how can I remove it?
2. Why doesn't the SDK actually wipe out all the cached session data after calling the [[FBSession activeSession] closeAndClearTokenInformation] method? Are there additional steps I need to take to completely remove all of the previous Facebook Session Information?

Comment: Hi even I am facing the same issue. Have you found a solution?

Comment: facing the same problem.

Comment: facing same problem.....

Answer (score 1):

iOS caches facebook token also . You need to clear it as well to get rid of old token by

```
ACAccountStore *store = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
        NSArray *fbAccounts = [store accountsWithAccountType:[store accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook]];
        for (ACAccount *fb in fbAccounts) {
            [store renewCredentialsForAccount:fb completion:^(ACAccountCredentialRenewResult renewResult, NSError *error) {

            }];
        }
```